# PHP Error, Undefined offset: 0 in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

When I send a request this page, I got an error like this :

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 0
Filename: letters/imprest_request.php
Line Number: 149
```

## My Controller

```
public function imprestDocument()
{
    $office = $this->session->userdata('office_id');       
    $request = null;
if(!($office == 106 || $office == 48))        
       $request = ($GP['Letter-request_imprest']) ? $this->Documents_model->getRequestImprest(0, 1) : [];
if (!empty($request)) {
         foreach ($request as $key => $item) {
          $view = explode(',', $item->view_status);
          $status = $office == 48 ? $view[1] : ($office != 48 && !empty($office) ? $view[0] : $view[2]);
          $index = ltrim(date('m', strtotime($item->imprest_date)), 0);
                if ($status)
                    $months[$index]['viewed']['request'][$key] = $item->imprest_date;
                else
                    $months[$index]['new']['request'][$key] = $item->imprest_date;
            }
        }
$this->render('documents/imprest_index', $meta, $this->data);
}
```

The Line Number 149 is my View as : (The error Line)

```
<img src="<?= base_url() ?>public/letter/footer/<?= $page[0]->sign_id ?>.jpg" >
```

The result of `Documents_model->getRequestImprest(0, 1) : []` is working fine in PhPMyAdmin and outs the relevant records as well.

How can i fix this error? Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an empty array then the array key 0 will not exist.
This is just a PHP notice, not an error, you may want to check the $page is not an empty array first as the image would not load anyway (I assume it requires the sign_id)
Also, you can put your URI inside base_url :)

```
<?php if(isset($page[0]) && is_object($page[0])){?>
<img src="<?= base_url("public/letter/footer/" + $page[0]->sign_id + ".jpg") ?>" >
<?php }?>
```